# Temporarily ownership and Dependency/Customization of NFTs

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155, cryptoeconomics

In NFTs is there way to create a system where 2 NFTs (**A** and **B**) can be confirmed to be owned by the same owner and a new NFT (**Z**) is created that is dependent on the 2 primary NFTs (**A** and **B**).

By dependent, I mean is there a way to implement that if **A** and/or **B** leave the owners wallet, **Z** will be burned?

Maybe through some use of escrow smart contracts?
There is an option for having **A** and **B** staked the generate **Z** but there still would need that dependency if possible.

Also can **Z** be customized in a way that it can't be allowed to leave the owner's wallet?

Comment: hi @mook please follow up you have answers here

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to implement token Z you are describing as an ERC-721 token if it is done by the entity that deployed token A/B.

Here is a simple thought experiment to prove that by counter example. Assume you want to make an NFT that burns when you sell a CryptoKitty. Then assume you deploy one trillion of those contracts. Now sell a CryptoKitty. It is not possible to emit one trillion transfer (burn) events in one blockchain block. qed

You could perhaps do this instead with some other NFT token that is not an ERC-721 (or ERC-1155) but that would be boring.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas off the top of my head ...

ERC-721 has `ownerOf(tokenId)` and that could be used to identify if an address owns **A** and **B**.

Then I think you would use `approve` and `safeTransferFrom` as needed

Maybe in the NFT Contract, the NFT struct could have something like `isDependant` so that you can keep track of which NFTs are **A's** and **B's** and which are **Z's**

Answer (score 0):

Limit the logic to your needs over OpenZeppelin's [ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol)

A high level flow could be implementing functionality:

1. `mintZ()` checks if msg.sender owns A and/or B  > then mint Z
2. `transferAorB()`  transfer A and/or B > then burn Z
3. Limit transferring of Z

Do refer the docs: [ERC1155 Primer](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155) / [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155)